# How can I change the lazyload module in routes to normal module?

Tags: angular

Version:

```
ng version:
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
node: 6.10.2
os: win32 x64
@angular/common: 4.1.1
@angular/compiler: 4.1.1
@angular/compiler-cli: 4.1.1
@angular/core: 4.1.1
@angular/forms: 4.1.1
@angular/http: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser: 4.1.1
@angular/platform-browser-dynamic: 4.1.1
@angular/router: 4.1.1
@angular/cli: 1.0.0-rc.1
```

My project used to use lazyload modules in routes, such as:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'global-config', loadChildren: 'app/modules/act-widget/main.module#GlobalConfigModule' }
];
```

But we have too many lazyload modules. It makes our building process slowly(92% chunk asset optimization).
So we make a decision to discard lazyload modules.

But when I change to this:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {GlobalConfigModule} from '../modules/global-config/global-config.module';

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'global-config', loadChildren: () => GlobalConfigModule }
];
```

Error appears:

```
ERROR in Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Function calls are not supported. Consider replacing the function or lambda with a reference to an exported function (position 12:42 in the original .ts file), resolving symbol routes in E:/pgg_oa/src/app/container/container-routing.module.ts, resolving symbol AppRoutingModule in E:/pgg_oa/src/app/container/container-routing.module.ts, resolving symbol AppRoutingModule in E:/pgg_oa/src/app/container/container-routing.module.ts, resolving symbol AppRoutingModule in E:/pgg_oa/src/app/container/container-routing.module.ts
```

My question is:

How can I change our lazyload modules into normal modules with the least cost?

Comment: Just update you cli to the latest version and it won't be that slow anymore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should create an exported function, and use that as the `loadChildren` value. The problem is, that you have to create a function for every module:

```
export function getGlobalConfigModule(): typeof GlobalConfigModule {
   return GlobalConfigModule;
}

export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'global-config', loadChildren: getGlobalConfigModule}
];
```

The initial startup time of the application will be a lot slower though, I'm not sure you would want to make that decision. A build process takes a long time, because of the AoT compilation being done. Perhaps investing in new disks with high I/O will improve build time